# What are some options for python's DataFrame like structure in java?

Tags: java, python, pandas, dataframe

I have a service written in python.

This service uses DataFrame from pandas.

The thing is that it (the service) should be translated to Java.

For that I need a similar library in Java. (or is there other way to achieve this?)

I would like to know what are some options for this.

Till now I have joinery library

Answer (score 7):

Besides [joinery](https://github.com/cardillo/joinery) you could also take a look at [tablesaw](https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw) library. Here is link to a brief tutorial: https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/gettingstarted